# Unable to get value of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <textarea name="message' id="myarea">This is it</textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id="savebutton" value="Go" /> <p id="fuck"></p>
</div>

<script>

$('#savebutton').click(function() {
    var text = $('#myarea').value();
    alert(text);
}); 

</script>
```

On click I get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'value'

Comment: this is jQuery, not pure javascript (I added the tag)

Comment: You may want to edit your code samples for obvious profanity before posting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things, use `val()` instead of `value()`. And

```
<textarea name="message' id="myarea">This is it</textarea>
```

is invalid. Use

```
<textarea name="message" id="myarea">This is it</textarea>
```

instead. Note the `name="message'`.

Answer (score 4):

It's `.val()`, not `.value()`.

If you do your development with your developer console open, you'll see there's a *TypeError*. This should be the first place you look when something isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The proper jQuery function is `val()`, not `value()`.

That said, a unicorn has just been brutally murdered due to your code. Try [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) instead:

```
document.getElementById('savebutton').onclick = function() {
    var text = document.getElementById('myarea').value;
    alert(text);
};
```

EDIT: You also have mismatched quotes in your textarea's attribute values. Correct those, otherwise even this won't work ;)